# MySql datatype versus PHP formatting whilst not losing numeric sorting capabilities

Tags: php, mysql, types, formatting

See http://pdga-europe.com/standings-2015/

It's probably the simplest question you've seen in a while, but I'm stumped.

I am importing an XLS sheet to MySql database, and most data is integers, but some (really, only some) are fractions (at an exact .5)

Data type gets set to DECIMAL (4,1) by PHPMyAdmin, and all math is correct (I'm sorting all data DESC (for the ones with "0" as totaled, I'm using a non-visible column "totaled" to sort by).

What I want to see is the following:

All integers in that particular column (ET3) to display as integers (and not as xxx.0), and ONLY the others as yyy.5?

VARCHAR would at least DISPLAY it right, but it would obviously prevent me from sorting the data in any way other than alphabetical (where 9 all of a sudden comes before 88).

What road should I take to get this right?

Should I find the correct data type, or should I do the formatting in PHP?

Currently my data gets generated this way:

```
<..query bla bla ..>
printf("
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>\n",
$row["ET3"]);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the data type storing these values, because you really dealing with a matter only of display logic.  Internally, as long as some of them have a decimal part, all should be stored with a decimal part as a numeric type, rather than as a `VARCHAR` type.

So you should handle the display logic in PHP, and it can be done many different ways. Retrieving values from MySQL, you will have a string rather than a PHP float value in `$row['ET3']`, making it easy to handle with basic string operations [like `substr()`](http://php.net/substr). You may test if the last two characters of are `".0"` and [truncate it with `intval()`](http://php.net/intval). For example:

```
// Intval truncates the .0
echo intval('9.0');
// 9
```

Using a ternary to perform the switch in one line:

```
echo substr($row["ET3"], -2) == ".0" ? intval($row["ET3"]) : $row["ET3"];
```

That expression stuffed into your existing `printf()` works as:

```
printf("
<tr>
<td>%s</td>
</tr>\n",
(substr($row["ET3"], -2) == ".0" ? intval($row["ET3"]) : $row["ET3"]));
```

Which can be expressed in expanded form as something like this, though the ternary above is more compact in your existing `printf()` context.

```
if (substr($row["ET3"], -2) == ".0") {
  // Truncate to an integer
  // intval($row["ET3"])
}
else {
  // Return the full original value (N.5)
  // $row["ET3"];
}
```

Finally, if you want to use this in more than one place, consider wrapping it in a function:

```
function truncInt($value) {
 return substr($value, -2) == ".0" ? intval($value) : $value; 
}
```

Then just use `truncInt($row["ET3"])` in your original `printf()`...

Comment: Excellent, Michael! Just copied and pasted, and it works like a charm, see updated http://pdga-europe.com/standings-2015/

Comment: @HansN Glad to help. See also my recent addition on placing this in a function for reuse. And good luck.

Comment: oh, that's even cooler, as i'll indeed be using it for [ET5] and [ET10] as well :)